# the usage of "susceptible to"

Tags: word-usage

I thought I was informed the usage of "susceptible", which is, `to be susceptible to + noun`

> He's highly susceptible to flattery. [src](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/susceptible?q=susceptible)
>
> She isn't very susceptible to flattery. [src](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/susceptible)
>
> These plants are particularly susceptible to frost. [src](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/susceptible)

In the examples above, all of the words come after "susceptible to" are nouns.

However, [Oxford Learner's dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/susceptible?q=susceptible) says

> [not usually before noun]

Could someone make up a situation where "to be susceptible to" is not with a noun or a noun phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary definition you're linking to is about "**susceptible**", not "to be susceptible to".

In all of your examples, susceptible is used before a preposition ("to"), not a noun ("flattery"/"frost").

You are correct that "susceptible to" is generally before a noun (or noun phrase).